# Sideloading an image from a function in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, assets, image

I need to be able to side load an image and attach to an entry.

My image is coming from an external url... such as http://someplace.com/image.jpg - i can store this in a temporary file so its locally accessible.  But then how do I upload this image (without using $_POST or $_FILES) and attach to an entry.

The method i'm trying at the moment i'm using something like:
uploadNewAsset(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folderId)

But UploadedFile seems to only want to accept POST variables, unless i'm missing something

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see an entire example how to fetch a file via curl, save it into an asset and relate it to an entry [here](https://github.com/Anubarak/api-caller/blob/master/src/services/ApiCallerService.php)

```PHP
// get the entries service
$entries = Craft::$app->getElements();

// get the entry
$entry = \craft\elements\Entry::find()->one();

// somehow grab the path of your image
$client = Craft::createGuzzleClient();
$response = $client->get('https://www.google.com/logos/2018/halloween18/rc5/cta.png');

$image = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$path = Craft::$app->getPath()->getTempPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . 'someFile.png';
FileHelper::writeToFile($path, $image);

// the folder for the image
$folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->getFolderById(1);

// create a new asset
$asset = new \craft\elements\Asset();
$asset->tempFilePath = $path;
$asset->filename = 'someFileName.jpg';
$asset->title = 'someTitle';
$asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
$asset->volumeId = $folder->volumeId;
$asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
$asset->setScenario(\craft\elements\Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
if($entries->saveElement($asset) === true){
    // file was saved 
    $entry->setFieldValue('assetFieldHandle', [$asset->id]);
    $entries->saveElement($entry);
}
```